# Prove exists consecutive integers $s,s+1,\dots,s+i$ such that $m_{i}|s+i$, if $m_{0},\dots,m_{r}$ are positive integers coprime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers

If $m_{0},m_{1},\dots,m_{r}$ are positive integers with $(m_{i},m_{j})=1$ for $i\neq j$, prove that exists consecutive integers $s,s+1,\dots,s+i$ such that $m_{i}|s+i$ for all $1\leq i \leq r$.

I really don't know how to approach to this problem. Any tips?

Comment: The bounds on your index $1\le i\le r$ does not make clear whether it must be the case that $m_0\mid s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want the solution to the following system. Since $\gcd(m_i,m_j)=1$ so we can apply **Chinese Remainder Theorem** to guarantee the existence of a solution.
\begin{align*}
s & \equiv 0 \pmod{m_0}\\
s & \equiv -1 \pmod{m_1}\\
s & \equiv -2 \pmod{m_2}\\
\vdots & \equiv \vdots\\
s & \equiv -r \pmod{m_r}
\end{align*}